# How to throw an error to parent catchError?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Simulation of my code:
I have a method `load()`, which makes a request to get an id. After that, I need to approve this id by `approveId()` method, which makes some post request.
In case of successful approve id, I need to log it. If id isn't approved, I need to retry getId request and approve it. If id isn't approved after retrying - log to the console a message that approve was failed.

```
load() {
    this.httpService.getId().pipe(
      switchMap((id: string) => this.approveId(id)),
      tap(() => {
        // some successful operations
        console.log('Success got ID');
      }),
      retry(1),
      catchError(() => {
        console.error('Approve was failed');

        return of(null);
      })
    )
  }
```

```
approveId(id: string) {
    this.httpService.approveId(id).pipe(
      first(),
      tap(() => {
        console.log('Success approved');
      }),
      catchError((error) => {
        // ???

        return of(null);
      })
    )
  }
```

In this case, let's suppose that `this.httpService.getId()` always returns a valid id.
`retry(1)` operator should be called in case of an error in approve request, so what can be done in approveId's `catchError` operator to throw an error to outer `retry` and on repeat error to outer `catchError`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just rethrow the error as an `error` notification with `throwError()` from `catchError()`:

```
import { catchError, throwError } from 'rxjs';

...

catchError((error) => {
  // ???

  return throwError(error);
})
```